# Searching for a XML-FO Processor

Tags: .net, xml-formatting

I been trying to find an Free/Open Source XML-FO processor that i could use in .NET applications but i havent had luck finding one. Do anyone know of one that i could use?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call [apache fop](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) from .net

[This guy](http://radio.javaranch.com/balajidl/2006/01/16/1137440142333.html) posted some info on getting it to work.

I'm sure a little more searching and you could get some better/more examples.

Comment: I found this article that comments about a .NET component called nFOp which is a .Net port from the Apache XML Project's FOP Java source. Il be doing some test and see how it does. Thanks Again.

URL of article:
http://alainrivas.blogspot.com/2008/10/aspnet-xsl-fo-nfop-web-hosting.html

Comment: Oh...i totally forgot about nFOP...one of the guys i work with used that.

Comment: I found another .NET component called fonet , u can find more info at: http://fonet.codeplex.com/. This seem good component.

Comment: I test yesterday the nFOP xml-fo component for .net it worked perfectly. Tho i dont like much it depends on some J# .net libraries but it works well.

Answer (score 5):

There is a free XSL-FO processor for .NET called [FO.NET](http://www.codeplex.com/fonet).

I'm using it and it works just fine for my needs.

[EDIT]
Sorry, just noticed someone else had already made a comment about FO.NET...

Comment: Uhm, nope, you're the only one. And I would recommend this above the implementations that require VisualJ# to be installed. FO.NET is written in C#. So +1 for you.

Comment: we use this at work. it does what it says on the tin. Would love the project to be active enough that there was a nuget package for it but hey, it's stable, it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nfop which is a .NET port of Apache's fop.

You can find it at http://sourceforge.net/projects/nfop/.

Some of it's limitations are:

- It doesn't support FO 2.0
- It can only run on 32-bit servers (because it requires a J# SDK be installed)
- The image support is not always reliable (doesn't support .gif urls but does as file paths)
- Some of the padding and margin attributes don't always render

As a starter tool it's great.  It does the simple formatting that you might expect to be able to do.  If you want to do fancy PDf stuff like bookmarks and table of contents, you will probably need to upgrade to professional FO processor.